# Wrong example response being sent with modified request body

Tags: json, postman

I have a single request "auth" that simply sends the below raw data..

```
{ 
    "password": "123",
    "userName": "rob"
}
```

and i have setup two examples.  The first called "success" takes the above request and returns..

```
{
    "user": {
        "profile": 1234
    }
}
```

I then wanted to test scenario whereby the password (and eventually user name) is empty so i can see error being returned.  So a second example "No Password" sends

```
{ 
    "password": "",
    "userName": "rob"
}
```

and the response is

```
{
    "id": {
        "code": 1
    },
    "errorObject": [
        {
            "errorCategory": "INPUT_ERROR",
            "errorName": "PWRD_EMPTY",
        }
    ]
}
```

Now the issue is that regardless of what request i make i always get back the error response.  I've tested this a few times and i think it's actually just returning whatever the newest example created was.

Is Postman able to detect differences in json data in the request body?  I have tried creating a second "auth" request, one for success scenario and the other for the failure but this didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "newest example created" could you elaborate? Also it would be helpful if you could share snippet of your API as well.

Comment: So originally i created the "success" example first and then the "No Password" example and i was always receiving the "No Password" response back with or without the password field set.  If i started from scratch and this time created the "No Password" example first followed by the "success" example.  Sending a request with or without the password field set would result in me always receiving the "success" response.  I hope i made sense!

Comment: Yes! I totally get you. You are always getting the response of the second request that you make.

Comment: Yes, that's correct